# Laravel 6. Get multiple data from a dynamic table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I tried to get all the data from a table which rows were added dynamically. But on the controller, I only get only one row (the first row).

```html
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Description" class="form-control" name="desc[]"> </td>
    <td> <input type="number" placeholder="0" name="txtAmt[]" class="form-control computeTotal"> </td>
    <td style="text-align-last: right;">
        <button class="removeRow btn btn-danger" style="height: 20px; padding-top:2px;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

This is my tbody and to add rows,

```js
$('#addRow').on('click', () => {
    $('tbody').append('<tr>'+
        '<td colspan="2"> <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Description" class="form-control" name="desc[]"> </td>'+
        '<td> <input type="number" placeholder="0" name="txtAmt[]" class="form-control computeTotal"> </td>'+
        '<td style="text-align-last: right;">'+
        '<button class="removeRow btn btn-danger" style="height: 20px; padding-top:2px;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>'+
        '</td>'+
        '</tr>');
});
```

and this run smoothly. I just want to know why on the controller, I only get the first row even if I have e.g 5 rows added and filled up on the UI?

This is the function on the controller.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if(count($request->desc) > 0){
        foreach($request->desc as $key => $value){
            $data2 = array(
                'description' => $request->desc[$key],
                'amount' => $request->txtAmt[$key]
            );
        }
    }
    dd($data2);
}
```

returns

[image]

[image]

this is my form

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('saveShopService') }}">
          @csrf
          @include('alerts.success')
```

and the route (under auth middleware)

```
Route::post('saveShopService', 'ShopController@store')->name('saveShopService');
```

The js file is imported on the app.blade.php that has been extended from the main file.

I tried to add another 1 **tr** on the UI manually, then hit submit, I get 2 rows on the request. I wonder why I can't get the other rows' textbox values when done with adding using jquery.

Comment: are you sure you transfer all the data into server?

Comment: @RomanBobrik yes sir. I did. I edit the post. DD returns only the first row details. Other than that, nothing follows.

Comment: show then how you make request to server

Comment: and you just submitting form, which contents your table with inputs?

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting array every time inside the loop.

```
            $data2 = array(
                'description' => $request->desc[$key],
                'amount' => $request->txtAmt[$key]
            );
```

You need to change as below:

```
            $data2[] = array(
                'description' => $request->desc[$key],
                'amount' => $request->txtAmt[$key]
            );
```

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure with this. It seems I can't get all the request in array. I don't know why. I set the append to the same as what the **name** attr of the input from the first row.

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed this. Thanks

I just fixed the position of opening tag of

> form

and the closing

> /form